# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ent_text' cannot be null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am developing a website with the symfony2 framework and am using Doctrine as my ORM. I have two entities that form a simple bidirectional OneToMany relation, the one side being Category and the many side being Entry. To let a user manage categories and corresponding entries I am using the SonataAdminBundle. I have also implemented a simple file upload in the admin bundle. Whenever I try to save a new entry, I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Entry
(title, ent_text, img, author,  pub_date, slug, cat_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
with params ["BLa", null, "asdf.jpg", "User", null, "bla", 1]:
```

I have absolutely no clue where this is coming from, especially since all the necessary field in the form are filled. Here are all the corresponding classes, I have decided to post pastebin links for better readability:

1. Entry entity:
   http://pastebin.com/vp8Ym4wz
2. Category entity:
   http://pastebin.com/vLMJyxdW
3. EntryAdmin class: Sorry, had to post here, I'm only allowed two links due to reputation. And for some reason the first few lines wont format properly, sorry about that aswell.

```
namespace S4P\MainBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class EntryAdmin extends Admin {

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $formMapper
            ->add('category', 'entity', array('class' => 'S4PMainBundle:Category', 'property' => 'title'))
            ->add('text', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('image', 'file', array('required' => false))
            ->add('author', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('title', null, array('required' => true));
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper) {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('text')
            ->add('img_name')
            ->add('author')
            ->add('title');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
        $listMapper
            ->add('text')
            ->add('img_name')
            ->add('author')
            ->add('title');
    }

}
```

I am grateful for any help.

Regards
Bene

Answer (score 1):

Using Symfony 2.4, I have a similar issue with non-required fields that I do not want to be null (I want to default to '' or 0). Using the Symfony form builder, if a field is not required and also left blank (text) or default (choice), the entity field will be filled with the NULL value. The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data) says that you should add a `empty_data` attribute on the form field, to specify what the alternative empty data value should be.

```
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
     'choices' => array(
         'm' => 'Male',
         'f' => 'Female'
     ),
     'required'    => false,
     'empty_value' => 'Choose your gender',
     'empty_data'  => ''
));
```

Based on the Documentation this appears to be the correct solution.

But unfortunately so far this doesn't work for me either. I continue getting an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'gender' cannot be null
```

And the query, includes `null` for that field, so it would appear the `empty_data` attribute is not having any effect.

NOTE: my entity defines the default value as '' and does not have nullable=true. The database is set to NOT NULL. So I can't see any reason these should submit as NULL.

Comment: Thank you buddy! This really saved me. String-like fields like text, url, email, choice, shouldn't be stored in the database as `NULL` if empty, but rather as an empty string. The option `empty_data` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add nullable=true to any of the columns which can be null.  The fact that you have each property mapped to a form field does not preclude that property from ending up with a null value.

You will need to update your database schema after updating your annotations.

Comment: Hi Cerad, thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to mention, the column should NOT be null. That is exactly the problem. The mentioned column holds the text of an entry without which the entry would be useless. The problem is that even if I enter text into the corresponding form field the field seems to be null on arriving at the database. This implies the fact the the value entered into the field is lost somewhere along the way.

Comment: The insert statement shows two columns, ent_text and pub_date with a value of null.  I don't see either of them in your form stuff.  Consider setting them to a non-null value in your entity.

Comment: @Cerad. If you want a field that defaults to 0 or '' instead of NULL, and it is not required, what do you suggest? The docs say you can use `empty_data` attribute: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data But that doesn't work for me, the field still gets submitted with NULL value if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

As nothing worked I have decided to remove the field from the database and recreate it. For some reason this was the solution. As it being obvious that there is not such thing as magic, it must have been something that I have overseen in my Entry entity. Thanks anyway for helping.

Regards
Bene

Comment: I tried removing my field and recreating it, and it didn't fix the problem. Perhaps you did something else as well?